# sorting python pandas dataframe by matching values of two different columns and calculate the mean

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a text file that imported as pandas dataframe looks like:

```
       a   b  c   d      e
index
0      18  1  1 -30.47  0.746
1      19  1  1 -30.47  0.751
2      20  1  1 -30.47  0.801
3      33  2  1 -30.47  1.451
4      34  2  1 -30.47  1.534
5      35  2  1 -30.47  1.551
6      49  3  1 -30.47  2.297
7      50  3  1 -30.47  2.301
8      51  3  1 -30.47  2.351
9      64  4  1 -30.47  3.001
10     65  4  1 -30.47  3.085
11     66  4  1 -30.47  3.101
12    346  1  2 -28.47  0.601
13    347  1  2 -20     0.682
14    348  1  2 -28.47  0.701
15    362  2  2 -28.47  1.445
16    363  2  2 -28.47  1.451
17    364  2  2 -28.47  1.501
18    377  3  2 -28.47  2.151
19    378  3  2 -28.47  2.233
20    379  3  2 -28.47  2.251
21    392  4  2 -28.47  2.901
22    393  4  2 -28.47  2.996
23    394  4  2 -28.47  3.001
24    675  1  3 -25     0.596
25    676  1  3 -26     0.601
26    677  1  3 -22     0.651
27    690  2  3 -26.47  1.301
28    691  2  3 -26.47  1.384
29    692  2  3 -26.47  1.401
30    705  3  3 -26.47  2.051
31    706  3  3 -26.47  2.147
32    707  3  3 -26.47  2.151
33    721  4  3 -26.47  2.851
34    722  4  3 -26.47  2.935
35    723  4  3 -26.47  2.951
```

I have been trying to reorganize the dataframe as following: for each value in col two, for example value 1, there are multiple corresponding values in column three and four.For example

value 1 (col one) corresponds to: value 1 (col three), -3.47 (col four);
value 1 (col three), -3.47 (col four); value 1 (col three), -3.47 (col four).....value 3 (col three), -25  (col four); value 3 (col three), -26 (col four); value 3 (col three), -22 (col four)

and so on. I would like to create a new dataframe where for value 1 there are other three corresponding columns, 1,2 and 3, containing the mean of the three values of the original column four. The output should look like:

col 1, col 2,                    col 3,                  col 4

1      mean(-3.47,-3.47,-3.47)   mean(-28.47,-20,-20.47) mean(-25, -26,-22)

The output should contain all the values of column one, in this case 1,2,3 and 4 (table 4x3). I am not an expert in python, I have no idea how I should approach this task besides matching values in couple. Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df.groupby([2,3])[4].mean().reset_index(name='Mean').pivot(columns=3,index=2,values='Mean')
```

Output:

```
3      1          2          3
2                             
1 -30.47 -25.646667 -24.333333
2 -30.47 -28.470000 -26.470000
3 -30.47 -28.470000 -26.470000
4 -30.47 -28.470000 -26.470000
```

Comment: I get :                                                                                                           3    -30.47    -28.47    -26.47  -26.00  -25.00  -22.00  -20.00
2                                                              
1  1.914167       NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2       NaN  1.930182       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   0.682
3       NaN       NaN  2.130222   0.601   0.596   0.651     NaN
so what's the problem?